# Is it RESTful for a resource to have different values to different users?

Tags: rest

Two scenarios:

### Scenario 1 - Redacting information on a resource

Let's say I've got a `User` resource

```
id: string; 
username: string; 
address: string;
```

For privileged  users they may see:

```
id: "1", 
username: "bobby", 
address: "123 Foo Lane"
```

However for less-privledged users, they see:

```
id: "1", 
username: "bobby", 
address: "<REDACTED>";
```

Is this RESTful or no?

### Scenario 2 - Attaching user specific meta data to a resource

For example we have a Widget resource, which has raw data of the shape:

```
id: string; 
name: string;
```

But the response also returns access permissions information to the response, for example an admin user might see:

```
{
    data: {
       id: "1", 
       name: "foo",
    }, 
    _accessControl {
       canDelete: true, 
       canEdit: true
    }

}
```

While and ordinary user sees:

```
{
    data: {
       id: "1", 
       name: "foo",
    }, 
    _accessControl {
       canDelete: false, 
       canEdit: false
    }

}
```

The reason we might want to do this, is to change frontend behaviour in regards to this resource (eg not showing a delete button if the user can't delete the resource).

Is this RESTfuL? How else might the server hint at the access permissions for the resource?

(FWIW - if using ACL based permissioning - you could have an `acl` attribute on the resource, and client works out themselves whether they can edit the resource or not. However let's assume that's too costly for the the client to do).

This [answer here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/215997/109776) appears to suggest something similar - is the convention of prefixing an attribute with an underscore to denote that 'this is user specific' an inherently RESTful concept?

Comment: My scenario 1 appears to be a duplicate of this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/438401/in-restful-apis-whats-the-proper-way-to-have-different-resource-properties-bas?rq=1

Comment: Returning different content is perfectly fine as long as your server also returns a `Vary` header to prevent inappropriate caching.

Comment: It's your system and you define the rules ;) But I would not send access control information alongside data. I would pass this information with user information after login, say `{"firstName": "John", "lastName":"Doe", "acl":[ $whatever]}`

Comment: Perhaps I'm in ignorance of something, but in what way are you concerned your scenario would violate any RESTful principles?

Comment: @Hawkeye What I was wondering if if something to be RESTful - it needed to look the same to all consumers of it.

Comment: @amon - Very good point about caching - thanks.

Comment: @dwjohnston Ah, I see. Perhaps it will help to differentiate "Authorization" from "Statelessness". Statelessness (a principle of REST) means that the server does not track sessions (the state) nor the user's connection. When an API is "Stateless" it means "Authorization" and all information pertaining to your process have to be sent up. Providing data in this manner is often referred to as **consistent** and **reliable** and that probably add to the confusion. Your concern is about "Authorization" (showing information differently to different users), which is not **inconsistent**, just hidden.

Comment: @dwjohnston I would also add that in your scenarios, just because something shows as "redacted" to one user, or a Boolean value regarding permissions is different, that this does not violate any **consistency** of the data, this is just about **authorization**,

Comment: @Hawkeye - thanks - this is the kind of information/principles I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

**Scenario 1**

Yes, that is RESTful. There's a `User` resource, different clients can get different Representation of the object, nothing is wrong with that. What can make it not RESTful is how the request was made? E.g. do you use Authentication header or "session"?

**Scenario 2**

Not quite. Instead of returning some ACL permission object which interpretation specific to a client, you want to return hypertext links that allows client to manipulate the resource. This is easier to illustrate with a webpage that has an Edit link that takes the users to a page form they can fill and a Save button so they POST their changes.

Non-browser clients can do more than GET and POST requests, that's why the links are represented that way, i.e. `href` and `method`, so clients can do e.g. PUT requests.

The underscore prefixing `_links` is not RESTful, REST is an architectural style, not a set of rules that need to be followed. I believe `links` come from [JSON-HAL](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-kelly-json-hal-01.html#rfc.section.4) and the underscore is to identify reserved properties.